# UK citizen returning to the UK from the US as a retiree

Tags: uk-citizens, usa

I have dual US and UK citizenships and I am thinking of returning to the UK as a retiree with my US born spouse. I have been away from the UK for more than 50 years and I have no NI number. We have pensions and social security plus some investment income in the US that can be sent to a UK bank account. I have never paid any tax in the UK so I am unsure if we can get an NI number. Can we get one without looking like a freeloader for using the NHS?

Comment: Your greater concern is going to be getting [immigration documents for your spouse](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse).  In doing that, your spouse will pay for access to the NHS, but you'll have to show that your income is adequate (currently over GBP 18,600 annually, or roughly USD 25,000).